# angular-js change content on link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At the moment I have this:

HTML-Script

```
<div ng-app="home" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
    <div ng-bind-html="home" id="content">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

JS-Script

```
angular.module('home', []).controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
    $http.get("http://www.example.de/home/").success(function (response) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response;
    });
}]);
```

It works fine, but now I want change the content on click on an a-tag link link this:

```
<a href="#home/">Home</a> | <a href="#user/">User</a>
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: will you send new http get request via this links ? 
Like  "http://www.example.de/user" for <a href="#user/">User</a> and "http://www.example.de/home" for <a href="#home/">Home</a> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple function calling to make text changes, personally I would recommend using `ng-click=""` rather than `<a href="#"></a>` since haveing `#` is generally for [route changes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) in AngularJS.

According to your explanation I am assuming that you are pulling some HTML codes from other website and suddenly Angular just won't work. For `ng-bind-html` you will need to 'sanitize' it [since it is consider unsafe to ng-bind HTML code](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Nonetheless, here is the code I think that will work for you

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-init="content='test'"> 
    <div ng-bind-html="content | sanitize"></div>
    <a ng-click="changeContent('home')">Home</a> | <a ng-click="changeContent('user')">User</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .filter('sanitize', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }])

    .controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.changeContent = changeContent;

        function changeContent (content){
            if(content ==='home'){
                $http.get("http://www.example.de/home/").success(function (response) {
                    $scope.content = response;
                });            
            } else {
                // ......
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Edit: Spacing and typos

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can use {{}} to bind it. It's also known as double binding

```
 <div ng-app="home" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
        <div ng-bind-html="home" id="content">{{content}}</div>
    </div>

<a ng-href="{{yourLink}}">Home</a>
Just for demonstrate 
<button ng-click="yourLink = 'foo'">change the link</button>
```

Same here you can use angular scope to update the view

```
  angular.module('home', []).controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {
        $http.get("http://www.example.de/home/").success(function (response) {
            $scope.content = response;
        });
    }]);
```

> How angular update the view or content?
>
> Angular use watch and it watch all the scopes so whatever value will
>   be passed to the scope angular will trigger the digest cycle and
>   update the view or it's content

If you wish to use single binding you could simply put :: to this {{::yourLink}}
It make angular less to watch and work effectively